# pycharm module error NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, data-analysis

i am new in python and am using pycharm.when i run this code in my python idle its run but when i use this code in my pycharm its show error like this

my code is

```
import sys
import re

for line_string in iter(sys.stdin.readline,''):
  line = line_string.rstrip()

  date = re.search(r'date=[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+', line)
  date = date.group()

  print date
```

> line 8, in <module>
>     date = date.group()
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Answer (score 2):

`re.search()` returns `None` when it cannot match the pattern. You must always check the returned value before using it:

```
result = re.search(r'date=[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+', line)
if result is not None:
    date = result.group()
    print date
else: 
    # Do some error recovery here
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import sys
import re

for line_string in iter(sys.stdin.readline,''):
  line = line_string.rstrip()

  date = re.search(r'date=[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+'.decode('utf-8'), line)
  date = date.group()

  print date
```

Works that way. The expression contains non-latin characters, so it usually fails. You've got to decode into Unicode and use re.U (Unicode) flag.

Comment: The expression does not contain any non-Latin characters.